# CMake won't create object files and fails to link

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I'm trying to replace the build system of a project with CMake however, I am unable to make object files using CMake.

The project tree is like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
psg-play.c
psg/
  CMakeLists.txt
  psg.h
  psg-constants.h
  psg.c
```

The generated visual Studio 12 solutions fails to link with the error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'psg\Release\psg.obj'
```

On the psg build directory (psg\Release) there is a single file called 'psg' without extension at all.

The CMakeLists files are as follows. (Main CMakeLists.txt)

```
# Main
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

#Add all the dependencies
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/psg")
add_subdirectory (psg)

# --- The project executables ---
project (psgp)
# --- psg-play
add_executable        (psg-play psg-play.c)
target_link_libraries (psg-play psg)
```

psg/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(psg psg.c)
```

How can I correctly compile and ling those two files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing `project` command in the 
psg/CMakeLists.txt

```
project (psg)
add_library(psg psg.c)
```

Also the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html?highlight=add_subdirectory) for `add_subdirectory` mentions this:

> Typically the subdirectory should contain its own project() command invocation so that a full build system will be generated in the subdirectory (such as a VS IDE solution file).

Comment: Thanks! I was following the CMake tutorial which *does not* have that line in the library's CMakeLists

Comment: It will not have a project() if the library was part of a larger project. I mean if a root project includes a CMakeList.txt for a library the library CMakeLists.txt should not have a project() only the root CMakeLists.txt.